# Form Transparency overlays other elements

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, transparency

I have a transparent Windows Forms Form with a few custom usercontrols on it.
These controls have some transparency themselves.

The problem is that these controls overlap each other a little. The overlapping part is transparent so that shouldn't be a problem. Unfortunately it isn't working like it should instead of the transparency to show the control below it cuts out that part of the control.

Does anyone know what could be the problem here and how to solve it?

Comment: It is working like it should, transparency for windows just doesn't work the way you hope it does.  The background of the window is drawn by the parent window, you will not see the parts of *other* windows that you overlap.  You need to stop overlapping or switch to painting content instead of using controls.

Comment: @HansPassant do you mean the controls/components by window? Because it's kinda confusing to me when you talk about multiple windows when it's just one window.
-
So let me get this straight. If I set the background of a usercontrol to "Transparent" the background of the usercontrol will get filled with the Transparency Key of the form?

Comment: Your user control is a window.  Its background is drawn by the parent.  If you set the form's BackgroundImage property then you'll see that image in the user control as well.  If you put a button on that form and put the user control on top of that button then you *only* see the form's background, not the button.